# Close vote tests on StackOverflow

Tags: support, vote-to-close, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I've been seeing a few failed tests when I vote to close questions on SO. Apparently others thought the questions were valid enough, but they lacked (for instance) code, or were not code-related.

One example I just failed was [How to set projects to the recent view in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19862887/how-to-set-projects-to-the-recent-view-in-visual-studio), which in my opinion is not a proper question for SO (as it is not code-related, but caused by setting a specific option in VS).

Similarly, I recently voted to close some question that showed some kind of a flow diagram and asking how to achieve it, but without any code or other effort shown in it. I've noticed it happening with a few other questionable questions as well, at ended up getting blocked from reviewing for 2 days as a result.

Is there a way to somehow flag or otherwise object to the test result? I'm perfectly fine with being told I was wrong, but some of these questions still do not seem like a good fit. Perhaps they shouldn't be used as test questions, as they do lack some of the (what I consider to be) essentials (I.e. code, or what the user tried to solve their issue).

Edit: I think this is the link to the review mentioned: https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/3520037

Comment: @JohannesKuhn - I added one. Is there an easy way to spot failed reviews in the activity list? Or would I have to manually open them all to find them?

Comment: Thanks for the link. Afaik we allow questions about developer tools on SO.

Comment: Manually follow all the links. I treied some SQL on [data.se], but there are some other problems.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn Could that perhaps be changed to mark them more clearly? It'd literally require me to try and open several dozens of questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question you linked to ([How to set projects to the recent view in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19862887/how-to-set-projects-to-the-recent-view-in-visual-studio) IS on topic for stackoverflow.

From the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic):

> We feel the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of source code in them, but if your question generally covers…
>
> - a specific programming problem
> - a software algorithm
> - **software tools commonly used by programmers**
> - practical, answerable problems that are unique to software development
>
> … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

Comment: Yeah, that example was not the best. And now the "how to archive this" with flowchart?

Comment: @JohannesKuhn From the description given the  the "how to archive this" with flowchart? should have probably been closed. But to really answer that I need to see the question. AFAIK I don't have the ability to look at other people review history and I don't currently have the time to hunt for the question.

Comment: @NULL - you can see user review histories in their profile, activity area, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/users/569711/schmitzit?tab=activity&sort=reviews

Comment: @NULL [everyone has the ability to look at other people review history](http://stackoverflow.com/users/569711/schmitzit?tab=activity&sort=reviews). [I](http://stackoverflow.com/review/close/3516176) [found](http://stackoverflow.com/review/close/3494621) [a](http://stackoverflow.com/review/close/3516121) [few](http://stackoverflow.com/review/close/3495185) [audits](http://stackoverflow.com/review/close/3494621)

Comment: @JohannesKuhn Some of those were indeed the ones I was thinking of as well, particularly: Node at a longest distance from another node in a tree (http://stackoverflow.com/review/close/3516176) and OpenGL: Mix orthographic and perspective projection ( http://stackoverflow.com/review/close/3495185).

If both are decent enough, then it's probably just my idea of proper SO questions that is off.